# Consuming a RESTful Web Service: Controller Springboot error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-restcontroller

i'm studying how to consume rest controller in spring, i'm using eclipse to run the java/spring , I want to ask i got error like this when running the java. i already tried to search about the caused,etc still dont find the solutions. anyone know how to fix it?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConversionException: Type definition error: [simple type, class com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties$Value]; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties$Value` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 28] (through reference chain: hello.Quote["value"])
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:238)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:223)
    at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:725)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:680)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:332)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:15)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties$Value` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 28] (through reference chain: hello.Quote["value"])
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1290)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.impl.MethodProperty.deserializeAndSet(MethodProperty.java:127)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:369)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4001)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3072)
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235)
    ... 6 more
```

My Application Java

```
package hello;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

public class Application {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);
        log.info(quote.toString());
    }

}
```

Quote Java:

```
package hello;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties.Value;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Quote {

    private String type;
    private Value value;

    public Quote() {
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Quote{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Value Java

```
package hello;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;


@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)

public class Value {

    private Long id;
    private String quote;

    public Value() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getQuote() {
        return this.quote;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setQuote(String quote) {
        this.quote = quote;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Value{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", quote='" + quote + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Pom XML :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.resttemplate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hello1</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>hello1 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: in your `Quote` class you are using `Value` from `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties.Value`. I guess that's wrong. Guess you wanted to use the `Value` you created there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
package hello;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

// Below you are importing wrong Value class
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties.Value;
```

You are importing **com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties.Value** instead of your **hello.Value** class in **Quote.java** file

Replace your **Quote.java** file with the below code.

```
package hello;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import hello.Value;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Quote {

    private String type;
    private Value value;

    public Quote() {
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Value getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(Value value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Quote{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                ", value=" + value +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Spring can't create properly object because you don't have matching constructor in your classess

Add constructors to your classes:

**Value.java**

```
public Value(Long id, String quote) {
 this.id = id;
 this.quote = quote;
}
```

**Quote.java**

```
public Quote(String type, Value value) {
 this.type= type;
 this.value= value;
}
```

Last time I had the same problem:
[Invoke REST controller method returns 404 null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50570401/invoke-rest-controller-method-returns-404-null/50571134#50571134)